# Refering a variable as an array base and inside double quotes

Tags: shell, awk

I have a requirement which is to use variables inside double quotes. I am using the below code:

```
# each of these date,time are individual arrays and they have elements in it
access = {date,time,place,animal}
`for(acc in access)
{
       for(i in acc)
         print i,**acc**[i] > "/home/**acc**.txt"`
```

Now my requirement is, since `acc` is a variable, how can I access it inside the double quotes and also as an array base . Could you please share your views about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe AWK supports the kind of indirection you're trying to use.

As for using a variable with a quoted string, the variable must be *outside* the quotes, but adjacent strings and variables are concatenated.

```
print i, something > "/home/" acc ".txt"
```

If `acc` is "date" then the filename will be "/home/date.txt".

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. So cant I use the variable for array reference ... Is there any alternative for my first question

Comment: @User: Your first question is regarding double quotes. I addressed that in my answer. As for array references, you might be able to use a multidimensional array. See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional).

Comment: oh Thank you for your kind response .. Sorry I mentioned a wrong question number